# Colocar un div dentro de un tr

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Muestro registros en una tabla, cuando de click sobre un cliente tengo que mostrar debajo de el cierta información, para esto estoy usando el **plugin collapse** de *Bootstrap*, el problema es que el `<div>` que tengo dentro del `<tr>` lo pone afuera de la tabla y lo que quiero es que lo mantenga dentro del `<tr>`.

```
<table class="table">  
  <tr>
  <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Agosto</th>
  <th>Totales</th>
  <th>Pagado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr role="tablist">
   <td role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseListGroup1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
      QINGDAO
    </a>
   </td>
   <td>$10.00</td>
   <td>$10.00</td>
   <td>$700.00</td>
   <div id="collapseListGroup1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">Bootply</li> 
    </ul>
   </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Envuelve el div entre las etiquetas  `<td></td>` estas creando una estructura html no válida. El div como tal no es asumido como parte de la tabla y por eso te lo pinta fuera

Comment: @Xerif tienes razon pero lo que necesito es que ese <div> ocupe todo el ancho del <tr>

Comment: Simplemente ajustalo con css, por ejemplo con un `with: 100%;` al div

Comment: @Xerif lo que deseo es que ese div quede abajo de los <td> porque cuando se de click sobre un cliente se va a desplegar información de el

Comment: Entonces envuelve el div entre `<tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>` el colspan indica el numero de columnas que quieres que ocupe. Te deje un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que envolver el div entre las etiquetas `<td></td>` para que forme parte de la tabla, si quieres que ocupe una fila completa utiliza `colspan` en el td:

Ejemplo 1:

```html
<table class="table" border="1">  
 <tr>
  <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Agosto</th>
  <th>Totales</th>
  <th>Pagado</th>
    <th>Option</th>
 </tr>
 <tr role="tablist">
  <td role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
   <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseListGroup1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
   QINGDAO
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>$10.00</td>
  <td>$10.00</td>
  <td>$700.00</td>
  <td>
   <div id="collapseListGroup1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
   <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">Bootply</li> 
   </ul>
   </div>  
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Ejemplo 2 con `colspan`:

```html
<table class="table" border="1">  
 <tr>
  <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Agosto</th>
  <th>Totales</th>
  <th>Pagado</th>
 </tr>
 <tr role="tablist">
  <td role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
   <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseListGroup1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
   QINGDAO
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>$10.00</td>
  <td>$10.00</td>
  <td>$700.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <div id="collapseListGroup1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
   <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">Bootply</li> 
   </ul>
   </div>  
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```